# Check Field Exist in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection like this :

```
{ 
  "_id":"1321464"
  "Sex":"Male"
  "Age":"20" 
  "City":"Toronto" #Maybe this field are not present.
}
```

I want to find all my document with the field "City" not exist.
I try :

```
collection.find({"sex":"Male"},{"City":{"$exists": False}},{'Age': 1, '_id':0})
```

And i have this error message :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1239, in find
    return Cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 125, in __init__
    raise TypeError("skip must be an instance of int")
TypeError: skip must be an instance of int
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're passing three arguments to the `find` method. I assume you intended to pass a filter and a projection only. Try this:

```
collection.find({"sex":"Male", "City":{"$exists": False}},{'Age': 1, '_id':0})
```